# Allow a server role to have database specific permissions in sql2016

Tags: sql-server, roles, sql-server-2016

**Problem**

We have a server with multiple databases and we would like a way of **allowing a single group of users the ability to access or execute** a restricted set of objects in each database on a single server.

**Context**

This used to be managed via AD groups however we are trying to move away from AD groups to using a mix of server and DB roles. However, I don't want to have to add or remove a user from a db_role in each database or have to try to keep them all in sync. Is there a way to tie database permissions to a server role so I only need to maintain the users in the server role?

Comment: 1. Why don't you want to use AD groups that you say you already have?

Comment: 2. How can you imagine to grant a permission on db1.dbo.tbl1 and on db2.dbo.tbl2 to SERVER role?

Comment: @sepupic Ad groups are controlled by the domain admins rather than dba's, which we used to be okay with now we are trying to avoid the domain admin having all the keys to the all the cities. I can't quite imagine granting a database permission to a server role, I would appreciate any ideas on how to achieve the desired goal

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem with domain admins. But if you want to give a permissions only on some set of objects, you can do it only individually in every database. For some general permissions you can use server role, for example, if you grant ALTER TRACE to server role, all the members of that role will have SHOWPLAN in every database where they are mapped, the same thing for VIEW DEFINITION. But for object level permissions you cannot operate on server level